# How to remove case sensitive in google sheet query

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I queried from my sheet but its case sensitive. How can I remove it? My query as below:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(IF(QUERY('pending SKUs'!E2:AQ,"select F, G, H, L, M, N, O, I where E='tree' AND P <> 2 AND P <> 3 AND X='Pass' AND AQ <> 'Rejected'")="",0,
QUERY('pending SKUs'!E2:AQ,"select F, G, H, L, M, N, O, I where E='tree' AND P <> 2 AND P <> 3 AND X='Pass' AND AQ <> 'Rejected'")),""))
```

I want to include "tree tree", "TREE tree", "Tree tree" and any other possible case used between all the alphabets.

I also prepared the gsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DwgOVhsChyCw4NQtUyOx3q_4BoXLpBkN0U0RllNHFec/edit#gid=123192750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to include `lower()` function to your where condition part. Try-

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(IF(QUERY('pending SKUs'!E2:AQ,"select F, G, H, L, M, N, O, I where lower(E)='tree tree' AND P <> 2 AND P <> 3 AND X='Pass' AND AQ <> 'Rejected'")="",0,
QUERY('pending SKUs'!E2:AQ,"select F, G, H, L, M, N, O, I where lower(E)='tree tree' AND P <> 2 AND P <> 3 AND X='Pass' AND AQ <> 'Rejected'")),""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert E to lower then just check for lowercase "tree"

```
where LOWER(E)='tree'
```

Refer to:
[Making QUERY function case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693496/making-query-function-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 1):

**QUERY Case Sensitive range**

For general use and isolated problem, consider this solution. Take a look at this **[Example sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FR6enJee4sPsPO_jOVLKd4FdZX0SWnnZFzuw9wtC_cM/edit?usp=sharing)**

> Use this formula.

```
=QUERY( {A:C}, " SELECT * WHERE lower(Col1)='tree tree' ")
```

[image: QUERY Case Sensitive range]

**Explanation**

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) the range in this case `A:C` wrapped with [`{}`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) Array so that we would utilize `Col1, Col2,...` instead of `A, B,...` in the query.
- Notice we got all diffrent cases by setting the query to `" SELECT * WHERE lower(Col1)='tree tree' "` Meaning select everythig `*` where column 1 `Col1` is lowercase `lower(Col1)` is equal to `'tree tree'`, and in all cases it does.